# How to call a spider class from a normal class in Python?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have the following problem:

I wanna call a spider in a different class, like Jobs in Ruby on Rails. For instance:

```
class Foo:
  MySpider()
```

And then, call Foo() to execute my spider. I don't know if my point was clear enough, but I'll appreciate any help :)

Comment: Do you want one instance of `MySpider` shared across all instances of `Foo`, or should each instance of `Foo` have its own instance of `MySpider`?

Comment: I think each instance of Foo should have its own instance of MySpider. When I call Foo, it should call MySpider and if I call it again, another MySpider should be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several ways (even with functional programming), but I'm just going to show you a few:

**1. Constructor**

You can instantiate (I think that's what you mean by "call") `MySpider` in the constructor of `Foo`:

```
class MySpider(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('In MySpider __init__.')


class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('In Foo __init__.')
        MySpider()


Foo()

'''
prints:

In Foo __init__.
In MySpider __init__.
'''
```

But just note that a new instance of `Foo` will need to be created in order to instantiate and hold a reference to `MySpider`. If you need to keep the reference, just put `self.my_spider = MySpider()` in the `__init__`.

---

**2. Adding __call__**

Along with the `__init__` approach, you can add the `__call__` method. What this essentially does is allow the instantiated object to be called directly. If you have it `return self`, you allow a call chain to occur:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('In Foo __call__.')
        MySpider()
        return self


Foo()()()

'''
prints:

In Foo __init__.
In MySpider __init__.
In Foo __call__.
In MySpider __init__.
'''
```

Comment: I tried to call this way, but calling spiders from Scrapy I think is different than calling normal classes...